# concept diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

i'm not completely new to Latex/Tikz but for my previous tikzpictures it was enough specifying coordinates and connecting them or using arc's and some simple node commands. I searched alot for similar tikzpicture and couldn't believe nodody is using tikz for things like this. So i decided to ask my question here. I hope you can help me. I tried to do it with powerpoint but it's doesn't look good at all, especially in a letex document.
[image]

i would like to replace the rectangles of text3, text4 and text8 by this.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Florian

edit 250617:

```
     \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
   \tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    mybox1/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           text width= 1cm,
           minimum height=5 cm,
           minimum width =5 cm,
           text centered},
     mybox2/.style={
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw=black, very thick,
        text width= 1cm,
        minimum height=1 cm,
        minimum width =3 cm,
        text centered},
%    bigbox/.style={draw,minimum width = 10cm, inner sep=20pt,label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 %nodes
 \node[mybox1] (box1) {text 9};
 \node[mybox2, inner sep=5pt,left=0.5cm of box1]
 (box2) {text4};
 \node[mybox2, inner sep=5pt, below=0.5cm of box2] (box3) {text8};
 \node[mybox2, inner sep=5pt, above=0.5cm of box2] (box4) {text3};
 \draw (box2) --(box1);
 \draw (box3.east) --(box1.west); % how can i tell effective where i want to connect?
 \draw (box4.east) |-(box1);    % i want to connect with a square angle but with an staigt line (e.g. powerpoint figure)

% try to do the big rectangle for text12
% \node[bigbox=text12, fit=(box1)(box2)(box3)(box4)] (D) {}; %doesn't work (i tried to put the 4 boxes into one big box and put the text12 to bottom right)

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

i seem to not be able to post the result as i don't have enough reputation.

i didn't post a minimum example because i felt i'm on the wrong train. I didn't expect anyone to do my case but i hoped you could show me a thread where something similar was already solved

Comment: If there are already similar question, just give me the link for it :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far? (Why is the "thanks in advance" name different from your username? Just curious) The Tutorials 3 and 5, "A Petri-Net for Hagen" and "Diagrams as Simple Graphs" respectively both talk about node styles. Maybe you should have a look at them in the manual: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Since you have tried something so far, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: These node shapes certainly look **a lot** like those provided by the `signal` shape from `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}`. This is documented p 713 in [the PGF-TikZ manual](ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: @MichaelObermeist, see my answer below, now it provide complete MWE. It is design on basis of images given in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Off-topic*:

- Questions without MWE (Minimal (non) Working Example) is of type "do-it-for-me", which are unlikely to be answered here.

*On-topic*:

- Shapes for which you looking can be defined as follows:

```
   box/.style = {draw, inner sep=2mm, 
              minimum height=#1,  minimum width=22mm},
 box/.default = 6mm,
    SR/.style = {box, signal, signal to=east, on chain},
   SLR/.style = {box, signal, signal to=east and west, on chain},
```

(for details of `signal` shape see section *67.4 Symbol Shapes* in TikZ & PGF manual, v3.0.1a, pp. 712 -- 714) and then used as:

```
\node (n1) [SR]     {text 3};
\node (n2) [SR]     {text 4};
\node (n3) [SLR]    {text 8};
```

- This should serve as a starting point for your MWE :). The result can be something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
I indeed used the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, fit, quotes, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 6mm,
            > = Straight Barb,
         font = \sffamily,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {draw, inner sep=2mm, 
              minimum height=#1,  minimum width=22mm},
 box/.default = 6mm,
    SR/.style = {box, signal, signal to=east, on chain},
   SLR/.style = {box, signal, signal to=east and west, on chain},
fitbox/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner xsep=8mm, inner ysep=4mm, xshift=-4mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=1.5pt, font=\scriptsize\sffamily, auto}               
                        ]
\node (n1) [SR]     {text 3};
\node (n2) [SR]     {text 4};
\node (n3) [SLR]    {text 8};
%
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0mm and 8mm]
\path   let \p1 = ($(n1.north) - (n3.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node (n4) [box=\n1, below right=of n1.north east] {text 9};
%
\path   let \p1 = ($(n1.north) - (n2.north)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node (n5) [box=\n1, below right=of n4.north east] {text 10};
    \end{scope}
%
\node (n6) [fitbox, fit=(n1) (n4) (n5)] {};
%
    \begin{scope}[node distance=1mm and 22mm]
\coordinate[above=of n6.west |- n1] (n1a);
\coordinate[below=of n6.west |- n1] (n1b);
\coordinate[above=of n6.west |- n2] (n2a);
\coordinate[below=of n6.west |- n2] (n2b);
    \end{scope}
% dotted lines
\draw[very thick, densely dotted]
    (n1a) -- (n1a -| n1.west)
    (n1b) -- (n1b -| n1.west)
    (n2a) -- (n2a -| n2.west)
    (n2b) -- (n2b -| n2.west)
    (n3)  -- (n3  -| n6.west);
% inner arrows
\draw[->]   (n1) -- (n1 -| n4.west);
\draw[->]   (n2) -- (n2 -| n4.west);
\draw[<->]  (n3) -- (n3 -| n4.west);
\draw[->]   (n4.east |- n5) -- (n5);
% input arrows
\draw[->]   (n1a)+ (-2,0) to ["Text 1"  ] (n1a);
\draw[<-]   (n1b)+ (-2,0) to ["Text 2" '] (n1b);
\draw[->]   (n2a)+ (-2,0) to ["Text 5"  ] (n2a);
\draw[<-]   (n2b)+ (-2,0) to ["Text 6" '] (n2b);
%
\draw[<->]  (n3 -| n6.west) + (-2,0) to ["Text 7"] (n3 -| n6.west);
 % ouput arrows ?
\draw[<-]   ($(n2 -| n4.east)!0.5!(n3-| n4.east)$) to [pos=0.9,"Text 11"  ] + (4.4,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. To answer or not to answer, that is the question!

Comment: @Andrew, :) :) :). As far I understand OP question, I provide answer, however not give complete code for showed image ... I will provide it when OP will show any effort what he try to do in LaTeX so far.  I still wait to any his response.

Comment: @MichaelObermeist, any news?

Comment: Hi Zarko, my comment was not intended as a criticism. Indeed, I think that your answer is perfect! I always find it difficult when some one asks an interesting question but has put no effort into trying to answer it themselves. You shouldn't do everything for them, but you're tempted by the question. Hence my comment:)

Comment: @Andrew, your comment give me joy :).  I very liked it.

Comment: @Zarko no i don't have not enough time to do this. i decided to stick with visio altough it maybe looks worse but i have to finish the paper. But still thanks for trying to help

Comment: @MichaelObermeist, all is up to you. As far as follows from you question, you need only to put right text in nodes (should not be a big deal). Since answer solve your question, it will be nice to vote and accept it (regardless that you will not use LaTeX in your drawings).